# How add atributes of class in Protege 5.0?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, protege4

I am using Methontology as Methodology for the construction of a Ontology, in the task 7 for this methodology "Task 7: To define class attributes in detail", I know how to add the instance  attributes  in Protege but I don't know how to add the class attributes  in Protege 5.0.

I send  you the tables of class attributes and instance attributes, for show the diference between them

[Atributes of class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2r9w.png)

[Atributes of Instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqi7a.png)

Answer (score 2):

"Class attributes" that apply to the class rather than to instances of the class are modelled in OWL as annotation properties.

Comment: How I  model the class attributes in protege5?

Comment: By using annotation properties on the class itself. Select the class and the option to add annotations should be enabled.

Comment: But how add this class atribute with the semantic of OWL?. Because in owl the annotatiosn don't have any semantics from OWL point of view.

Comment: Owl semantics does not support class attributes; the only way to specify those with semantics attached is through punning, creating an individual with the same IRI as the class.

Comment: What would be the purpose of adding an annotation to a class. For instance, the class has max value 5. Why would someone do this besides documentation purposes? It has no meaning in OWL, right?

Comment: Exactly, for documentation. One could do something with the value but it would be a non standard extension to add semantic meaning via annotations.